# export data to csv without changing pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export

What is the proper way to export data to a csv file from rails.

I have an "export" link in my views

shows.html.erb

```
 <%= link_to "CSV", patient_record_path(format: "csv") %>
```

patient_record_controller

```
def show

    ....
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.csv {
        send_data RestClient.get(url, :accept => :csv), :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present', :disposition => "attachment; filename=data.csv"
        }
    end
end
```

When i click export I get the error

```
Template is missing

Missing template patient_record/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:csv], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/RubymineProjects/my_app/app/views"
```

it is also redirected to the url

```
http://www.host.com/patient_record/1.csv
```

I shouldnt even be redirecting pages, i simply want to export a csv file and keep on the same page

If I use ajax, the functionality works fine, but the file doesn't show up being downloaded in the broser

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a GET request to 'show' and it is throwing the error because it is looking for a show.html.erb file within the patients records controller. It would be possible to avoid the page from redirecting if you used jquery + ajax to issue the request by doing something like this:

```
$('#export_link).on ("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: whatever_the_patient_record_path_is,
    etc........
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but I was under the impression that if you used ajax then the download wouldn't show up in the browser

Comment: This works wonderfully, but as I just stated, the download doesn't "pop up" in the browser as a download

Answer (score 0):

creating a show.csv file that has <%=RestClient.get(url, :accept => :csv)%> works